# inheritance in Python deletes the original value

Tags: python

I have programmed a small inheritance problem in Python:

```
class Worker:


    def __init__(self,cod):
        self.cod=cod
        self.wage=0

class FactoryWorker(Worker):
    def __init__(self,cod,wage):
        Worker.__init__(self,cod,wage)
        Worker.wage=wage*1.10

    def printWage(self):
        return Worker.wage

class OfficeWorker(Worker):
    def __init__(self,cod,payperHour,numberHours):
        Worker.__init__(self,cod)
        self.payperHour=payperHour
        self.numberHours=numberHours

    def printWage(self):
        Worker.wage=self.payperHour*self.numberHours
        return Worker.wage
```

The problem that I have is when I make a couple of objects:

```
w1=FactoryWorker(2130,4000)
w1.printWage()

prints 4400

w2=OfficeWorker(1244,50,100)
w2.printWage()

prints 5000
```

but if I do again:

```
w1.printWage()
```

it does not print the original 4400, but it prints instead 5000

why is that? I want the variable wage to be declared as an attribute of the class Worjer and not individually in each one of the subclasses.

Any help?

Comment: Why would initialising a factory worker alter the base wage for all workers? Also, could you recheck your code and outputs - I get `TypeError`.

Comment: You are changing a wage in one of your printWage methods: `Worker.wage=self.payperHour*self.numberHours`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to know that you should refer to instance attributes via `self`, since you are doing that with `payperhour` etc. So I don't know why you aren't also doing it with `wage`.

```
class FactoryWorker(Worker):
    def __init__(self,cod,wage):
        super(FactoryWorker, self).__init__(self,cod,wage)
        self.wage=wage*1.10
```

(Also note the more Pythonic and flexible use of `super`, rather than calling the superclass explicitly.)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `Worker.wage` is a *class* member, meaning that all instances of the class will share the same value. What you want is simply `self.wage`, which is an *instance* member, meaning that each instance of the class will have its own value.

Comment: Per the question: *"I want the variable `wage` to be declared as an attribute of the class [`Worker`] and not individually in each one of the subclasses."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yes, it appears that the OP's request is at odds with their expectations of how the system works.